# Referencing an odbc connection within multiple functions

Tags: r, odbc

I have a database that I connect to within a function:

```
import_data <- function() {

    mis <<- dbConnect(odbc(),
                      Driver = "SQL Server",
                      Server = "Database_Name")
}
```

I'm assigning it to the global environment because I want it to be used in other functions.

After running this function, `dbIsValid(mis)` returns `True`.

However, when running another function, `dbIsValid(mis)` returns `False` within that function and `False` when outside of the function.

When I reference `mis`, I get the error message: "Error in connection_info(dbObj@ptr) : external pointer is not valid"

It feels like as soon as it's referenced in a different environment, the connection gets broken.

How do I avoid this issue and maintain a connection? It's important that the connection is maintained to prevent dropping the temp tables that are created during the process.

Comment: (1) Using `<<-` inside a function is bad practice in too many ways. If you need multiple functions to access the database, you should create your `mis` connection and pass it to your function as an argument, `import_data <- function(con) { DBI::dbGetQuery(con, ...); }`. (2) Frankly, I don't trust `dbIsValid` with `odbc::odbc()` connections, it relies on too many things outside the control and observability of the R side of things, too often providing false-positives; the fact that it returns `F` for you is interesting to me but not key.

Comment: (3) *"when running another function"* and then `mis` becomes unusable ... what is that other function doing? (4) Assuming that other function does not break or intentionally close the connection, then ... are you using `future` or any other parallel/forking multi-processing? (5) I use `odbc()` connections daily and pass the connection in many many functions, and every time the connection goes bad I can tie it back to (a) the function triggered a bad query that locked up the connection, and the error was explicit and obvious; or (b) my underlying network connection failed.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know that we have enough information. Please provide a reprex that includes 2 or 3 functions that do enough of what you do, and the connection fails. If you cannot reduce your code to clearly reproduce it, I'm not sure we're going to be able to infer much.